# How do I set my x-axis so that it only displays 1 month?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a dataset with the **sales count** and the **date** of those sales.

When I plot it on matplotlib, I get this:

[image]

Is there anyway for me to also display a **June** in between each year on the x-axis.

My code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

ax.scatter(df['date'], df['sales'])

ax.set(xlabel = 'Date', ylabel = 'Sales',
       title='Sales Data')

ax.grid(axis = 'x')

plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator(interval=6))` ?

Comment: @JohanC That gives me six months intervals from February to August. I just want June.

Comment: `MonthLocator((1,6))` to get them at January and June. `MonthLocator((6, ))` for only June